# React Hooks - Axios Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

[Solved] I'm trying to refactor a code I already have in react using react hooks. I'm getting this errors:

```
xhr.js:178 GET https://api.chucknorris.is/jokes/search?query= net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
onSearchSubmit @ App.js:15
(anonymous) @ App.js:21
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:19731
commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19769
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22853
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22820
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:22699
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:164
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

This is the API I'm using:
https://api.chucknorris.io/

With free text search:

```
https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query={query}
```

This is the github repo:

- https://github.com/analubarreto/chuck_jokes-hooks/tree/master/src

These are the files that are generating the errror:

- https://github.com/analubarreto/chuck_jokes-hooks/blob/master/src/app/App.js
- https://github.com/analubarreto/chuck_jokes-hooks/blob/master/src/features/SearchBar.js

PLEASE: if you're just going to say I'm asking wrong DON'T ANSWER AT ALL!! I've give all the information I think is needed.

Edit: Took me a while, but I realized it was a spelling mistake

Comment: I cloned your repo and it seems to be working fine. Have you pushed you latest edits?

Comment: https://api.chucknorris.is/jokes/search?query= , shouldn't it be https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/analubarreto/chuck_jokes-hooks/blob/master/?file=/src/app/App.js
It's working fine and I am getting the API response. Refer to the screenshot.

Let me know if your expectation is different from this.

[image]